# Duplicar archivo .yml para correr comando test en Docker

Tags: docker, contenedores

Amigos no es mi fuerte docker y contenedores, tengo que realizar un test y necesito correr el comando test de react y jest, existe o tengo un archivo .yml que ejecuta y corre el comando start o build, lo que me han pedido es que duplique este archivo y cambie los comandos para ejecute la instrucción test, podrían apoyarme haciendo la configuración en base al archivo que han solicitado que dupliqué dejo el archivo o código para editar y correr el comando test, espero me puedan ayudar, como comente no es mi fuerte docker y contenedores.

el comando que uso para correr el start o build es este: `docker-compose -f developer.yml up --build`

Muchas Gracias

```js
version: '3'

services:
  app-dev:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/developer/app.Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: >    
      sh -c "ls -ls && yarn start" 
    volumes:
      - ./react/public:/react/public
      - ./react/src:/react/src
      - ./react/.env:/react/.env.development
    ports:
      - "8082:3000"
```

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solucione : dejo la modificación, duplique el archivo por test.yml y cambie en el codigo cambie start por test y lo ejecuto asi `docker-compose -f test.yml up --build`

```js
version: '3'

services:
  app-dev:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/developer/app.Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: >    
      sh -c "ls -ls && yarn test" 
    volumes:
      - ./react/public:/react/public
      - ./react/src:/react/src
      - ./react/.env:/react/.env.development
    ports:
      - "8082:3000"
```